# Вывод переменной php в ajax алерте

Tags: ajax, php

Есть переменная после `if()`... к примеру:

```
$msg = 'Вы авторизованы!';
```

и вот если она существует, требуется вывести алерт с этим сообщением без перезагрузки.
Просто с инклудами уже переборщил.
В аяксе полный ноль, хотелось бы увидать пример, дальше разберусь

Comment: вот и почитайте доки по аяксу и js прежде чем спрашивать. [аякс - это просто... вообще ничего сложного](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А я с собой полностью согласен,

> alert('<? echo($msg_show); ?>');  //это говнокод, тут уж больше добавить не чего.

Это не AJAX это просто непонятно что.

Если ты работаешь с Ajax? могу предположить, php + js или php + jquery. то данные получаешь не в виде переменных php а в виде JSON или xml. и их уже разбираешь на стороне клиента, а не кустарным методом.

Допустим так, это на скорую руку.

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
           url: "/ajax/addtocard",
           data: {name:nm}
            }).done(function(html) {
             var res = JSON.parse(html);
             alert(res.status); // выводишь любое переданное значение.
            }
        }) 
        }
 });
```

php

```
If (isset($_POST['name']))
    {
       $answer=array(
           'status'=>1,
           'msg'=>"Вы авторизованы!"
        );
      echo json_encode($answer);
    }else
    {
       $answer=array(
           'status'=>0,
           'msg'=>"Вы нифига не авторизованы!"
        );
      echo json_encode($answer);

}
```

ну и будет в

```
 var res = JSON.parse(html);
    alert(res.msg); // выведет сообщение
    alert(res.status); // выведет статус
```

Ну немного подумать и исправить в php скрипте = на =>

Вывести данные в консоль посмотреть что приходит, как приходит, приходит ли вообще.

Comment: суть понял, но я не могу понять, при выполнении php скрипта, в конце переменная $msg держит в себе сообщение о результате работы, далее мне его требуется вывести уже на другой странице алертом

Comment: var res = JSON.parse(html);
    alert(res.msg); // выведет сообщение
    alert(res.status); // выведет статус

почему то не срабатывает

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Jbhr4wS8

в файле error.php
http://pastebin.com/zGaTUeff


в чем беда? выводит только  echo json_encode($answer);

Comment: >//<?=THEME?> - это то откуда? и что это?

> echo json_encode($answer);
> include(THEME.'error.php'); // это что такое?

Что происходит то вообще? Что выводится? что не выводится, что срабатывает а что нет? ну это уже детство, направление то задано, дальше нужно немного пошевелить головой!

Comment: <?=THEME?> константа php с путями стиля

include(THEME.'error.php'); это инклуд файла где должен вывестись алерт

Comment: include(THEME.'error.php'); это инклуд файла где должен вывестись алерт

Ты понял что написал? Я дальше не буду ничего писать, т.к. тебе явно нужен не AJAX. Ты не понимаешь что такое Ajax, он тебе не нужен. Ты роешь не в ту сторону. Тебе в твоем вопросе говнокода поможет аффтар ниже @Zver25 думаю вы на пару сможете сделать нечто! Без обид но это факт.

Answer (score -1):

Похоже Вы не только в Аяксе не разбираетесь.

Ответ:
сохрани значение переменной, если оно меняется.

```
$msg_show = $msg;
```

далее где надо вывести значение пиши

```
alert('<? echo($msg_show); ?>');
```

А для Аякса все зависит от того что получаешь HTML или JSON.
Приведи код AJAX запроса и код PHP.

Comment: Это ответ, как правильно написал @eicto 

>прежде чем спрашивать. аякс - это просто... вообще ничего сложного


Ибо такой бред 

>alert('<? echo($msg_show); ?>');

Никто не пишет!

Comment: Я с тобой не согласен.

Код рабочий, для начинающих самое оно... А для доказательства что ты мега-крутой чувак предложил бы свое крутое решение, нежели не обосновано критиковать

Comment: Для начинающих, учиться делать так - это войдет в привычку и потом отразится на всем, так что нет необходимости пихать в человека грязь, чтобы она у него отложилась.

Comment: и опять таки ты не показал как делать правильно... просто сказа "вы все дураки". Почему бы не привести правильный пример? И хотелось бы узнать чем этот вариант так плох.